# OpenSSL and signals

Tags: c++, c, linux, openssl, signals

Socket functions like `send` and `receive` can be interrupted by signals. Because of this some extra code is needed, e.g. to check for `errno == EINTR`. This is described on corresponding man pages.

I wonder how this works when OpenSSL functions are used, e.g. `SSL_write`, `SSL_read`. Their man pages do not say anything about signals. I also tried to google for this, but without luck. Do you know if OpenSSL handles signals internally, or some extra code is needed? If yes, how to check if function call was interrupted by signal?

**Update:**

Looks that OpenSSL does not handle retries. It only sets the "should retry" flag on BIO object. So I need to use something like this to detect if call was interrupted and retry is needed:

```
int result = SSL_write(ssl, buff, length);
if ((result < 0) && BIO_should_retry(SSL_get_wbio(ssl)))
    // need to retry

int result = SSL_read(ssl, buff, length);
if ((result < 0) && BIO_should_retry(SSL_get_rbio(ssl)))
    // need to retry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As being a libray OpenSSL cannot make any assumptions on how signals are handled by the particular program using it. So it needs to handle the case of a system call being interupted on the reception of a signal.

A check whether it made sense to retry a failed `read()` is implemented inside OpenSSL.

Use `BIO_should_retry()` if `BIO_read()` (or `BIO_write()`) failed.

For an example read here: http://cvs.openssl.org/rlog?f=openssl/demos/bio/sconnect.c

The implementation's relevant code follows:

```
static int sock_read(BIO *b, char *out, int outl)
    {
    int ret=0;

    if (out != NULL)
            {
            clear_socket_error();
            ret=readsocket(b->num,out,outl);
            BIO_clear_retry_flags(b);
            if (ret <= 0)
                    {
                    if (BIO_sock_should_retry(ret))
                            BIO_set_retry_read(b);
                    }
            }
    return(ret);
    }
```

The relevant referred functions are here:

(`get_last_socket_error()` returns `errno` on most IXish platforms)

```
int BIO_sock_should_retry(int i)
    {
    int err;

    if ((i == 0) || (i == -1))
            {
            err=get_last_socket_error();

#if defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WINDOWS) && 0 /* more microsoft stupidity? perhaps not? Ben 4/1/99 */
            if ((i == -1) && (err == 0))
                    return(1);
#endif

            return(BIO_sock_non_fatal_error(err));
            }
    return(0);
    }


int BIO_sock_non_fatal_error(int err)
        {
        switch (err)
                {
#if defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WINDOWS) || defined(OPENSSL_SYS_NETWARE)
# if defined(WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        case WSAEWOULDBLOCK:
# endif

# if 0 /* This appears to always be an error */
#  if defined(WSAENOTCONN)
        case WSAENOTCONN:
#  endif
# endif
#endif

#ifdef EWOULDBLOCK
# ifdef WSAEWOULDBLOCK
#  if WSAEWOULDBLOCK != EWOULDBLOCK
        case EWOULDBLOCK:
#  endif
# else
        case EWOULDBLOCK:
# endif
#endif

#if defined(ENOTCONN)
        case ENOTCONN:
#endif

#ifdef EINTR
        case EINTR:
#endif

#ifdef EAGAIN
# if EWOULDBLOCK != EAGAIN
        case EAGAIN:
# endif
#endif

#ifdef EPROTO
        case EPROTO:
#endif

#ifdef EINPROGRESS
        case EINPROGRESS:
#endif

#ifdef EALREADY
        case EALREADY:
#endif
                return(1);
                /* break; */
        default:
                break;
                }
        return(0);
        }
```

For details see `sock_read()` to be inspected here: http://cvs.openssl.org/rlog?f=openssl/crypto/bio/bss_sock.c

(The sources quoted along with the indention used is from version 1.0.1e.)

Answer (score 0):

If a signal interrupts a system call that causes it to return an error, then the calling SSL function will return an error indication (e.g. -1) and `SSL_get_error` could return any number of errors depending on the state of the SSL.

Most likely, it would return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, or `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` (hopefully with `EINTR` in `errno`).  Other errors such as `SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT`, `SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT`, `SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP`, and `SSL_ERROR_SSL` are possible depending on exactly what you were doing.

For OpenSSL v1.0.2j, the error returned from `SSL_get_error` usually depends on the read/write state of the SSL structure and its underlying BIOs.  *Usually*, that will be `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` for a `SSL_read` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` for a `SSL_write`.  However, during the initial handshake and possibly during renegotiation (which can happen within a normal call to `SSL_read` or `SSL_write`) it looks like `SSL_get_error` can return `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` and `EINTR` should be in `errno` when the low level call was interrupted by a signal.  Also, during renegotiation there is always the possibility that `SSL_read` yields `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` and `SSL_write` yields `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`.

I would not recommend trying to directly consult the underlying BIOs the way you do in your update.  Instead, consult `SSL_get_error` and if it's a non-fatal error, then retry or take other appropriate action.